# Xamarin Azure Easy Table Connection CancelledByNetworkError exception

Tags: azure, xamarin, mobile, json.net

I'm a newbie in xamarin and azure easy table. I just want to try it out. I followed several examples like [cups of coffee](https://blog.xamarin.com/getting-started-azure-mobile-apps-easy-tables/) and todo item list in xamarin university. I deployed my easy table successfully. However when I tried to write my own connection and insert. It seems it doesnt work.

Below is my code for initialization:

```
var Client = new MobileServiceClient("http://appname.azurewebsites.net");
var path = Path.Combine(MobileServiceClient.DefaultDatabasePath, "escapedb.db");
var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore(path);
store.DefineTable<InventoryModel>();
await Client.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store);
inventoryTable = Client.GetSyncTable<InventoryModel>();
```

Below is my code for insert:

```
var test = new InventoryModel() { Id = "12344", Name = "Sample", Quantity = 1 };
await inventoryTable.InsertAsync(test);
await SyncInventory();
```

When it calls insert, it throws an error 
**Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync.MobileServicePushStatus.CancelledByNetworkError**

This is my inventory model:

```
 public class InventoryModel
{
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("quantity")]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

How to solve this exception? I have an internet connection.
I just want to communicate to my azure service.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> When it calls insert, it throws an error Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync.MobileServicePushStatus.CancelledByNetworkError

`MobileServicePushStatus.CancelledByNetworkError` means that your push operation was aborted due to network error. I would recommend you catching [MobileServicePushFailedException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.sync.mobileservicepushfailedexception(v=azure.10).aspx) when handling sync operation. For more details, you could refer to [Handling Conflict Resolution](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/client/#handling-conflict-resolution). Also, you could leverage [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) for collecting the network traces and retrieve the detailed error message to narrow this issue. Additionally, when handling sync operation, I would suggest you refer to [Detecting Connection State](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/client/#detecting-connection-state).

Also, you could try to access your mobile app via the browser to isolate this issue and find out whether the issue dues to the network of your device or not. For browsing your mobile app, you could refer to [The HTTP Table Interface](https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/27/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-13-the-http-table-interface/).